# How to have VLOOKUP pull multiple instances?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I currently have a sheet where I'm organizing launches.
[SAMPLE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2IsO0SM1JLJgd-omZ7qspv5MyFRYOqlJacT952RZSs/edit?usp=sharing)

Currently I have a overview sheet and a calendar sheet which pulls from the overview sheet according to date and event type.

```
=iferror(VLOOKUP(B$3&" "&$A4,Sheet1!$A:$D,4,0),"")
```

However, when there are multiple "TITLE EVENTS" on a single day, I have to create separate rows w/ "TITLE EVENTS 2" and "TITLE EVENTS 3" in order for VLOOKUP to differentiate and show all instances of title events on the calendar.

Is there a way (may be *a lot* more complicated) where I can just have a single "TITLE EVENTS" selection and have the sheet be able to create a new row under "TITLE EVENTS" on its own? (ideal look on sheet 3).

Comment: To get nth match [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68373672/9808063).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant option:

[See here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cV59vlGg3TB6Z5QmWR5cmvQAFAeqpjx2EkNnOBPzans/edit#gid=1357057281)

```
=IFERROR(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER('Date Registry'!$D:$D, ('Date Registry'!$A:$A)=(H$3&" "&$A5)), 4, 1), "")
```

Formatted:

```
=IFERROR(
    ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
        FILTER('Date Registry'!$D:$D,  ('Date Registry'!$A:$A)=(H$3&" "&$A5)),
    4, 1)
, "")
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this solves your problem:

I copied your sheet and modified it to look `Sheet 3` but with formulas.

You can see it [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oi8NVGsxeJDTRCYMKczbSHlKY81Y4g_nplEe3Bswplk/edit#gid=1357057281).

I used the following formula on the `Calendar` sheet:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER('Date Registry'!$D:$D,  ('Date Registry'!$A:$A)=(E$3&" "&$A$5)), ROW()-4, 1), "")
```

###### Explanation:

```
=FILTER('Date Registry'!$D:$D,  ('Date Registry'!$A:$A)=(E$3&" "&$A$5))
```

gets all values of the intended type (eg. TITLE EVENTS) and with the intended date.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(...), ROW()-4, 1)
```

The second parameter is the row number.

- Row 5 is the row with `TITLE EVENTS`.
- Therefore, `ROW() - 4` gives the 1-based index of the row relative to row 5.

The third parameter is column number but since the range is only one column, it's always 1.